# Masonry content don't show properly in bootstrap tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I have created masonry content with bootstrap tab. I have created html markup bellow

without masonry
[image]

```
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="masonary">
     <div class="masonry_area">
       <div class="single_content"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS Properties bellow:

```
 .single_content{
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
float: left;
width: 245px;
margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
padding: 3px;
position:relative
}
```

I have used activation js

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.masonary_area').masonry({
              // options...
              itemSelector: '.single_content',
              columnWidth:245
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now working masonry but I have clicked on tab menu of masonry content, It has been seen bellow
[image]

But when i am clicking on "inspect element with firebug", it is showing perfectly.
Please help me.

Comment: Seems a better fit for the [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) site of SE.

Comment: It is unclear what you problem is. A screenshot is not enough info to answer your question. You need to post a link or make a jsfiddle.

Comment: my masonry content not floating.

Comment: Would you mind posting a fiddle or demo?